# FINE logging not logging

Tags: java, log4j

**log4j.properties**

```
log4j.rootLogger=FINE, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %t %c:%L - %m%n

log4j.category.my.root.package=FINEST
```

**My Class**

```
public class MyClass {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName());


    public boolean download(String destinationPath) {
        HttpURLConnection con = null;
        int i;

        try {
            logger.log(Level.FINE, "Download URL {0}", new Object[] { url.toString()});
        con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);

        InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
....
```

Despite my breakpoint reaching the `url.openConnection();` line, the `Level.FINE` doesn't show up in my console.  Here's the console I do see:

```
INFO: Order: #298596(Status: 1)
15:00:58,532 DEBUG main org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl:158 - begin
15:00:58,532 DEBUG main org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl:295 - Obtaining JDBC connection
15:00:58,558 DEBUG main org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl:301 - Obtained JDBC connection
15:00:58,559 DEBUG main org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction:69 - initial autocommit status: true
15:00:58,559 DEBUG main org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction:71 - disabling autocommit
15:00:58,615 DEBUG main org.hibernate.SQL:104 - MY-QUERY
15:00:58,657 DEBUG main org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl:173 - committing
15:00:58,661 DEBUG main org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction:113 - committed JDBC Connection
15:00:58,661 DEBUG main org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction:126 - re-enabling autocommit
15:00:58,664 DEBUG main org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl:314 - Releasing JDBC connection
15:00:58,664 DEBUG main org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl:332 - Released JDBC connection
15:00:58,664 DEBUG main org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.ConnectionProxyHandler:219 - HHH000163: Logical connection releasing its physical connection
INFO: #298596: Importing...
```

How come I'm not seeing my own custom logging?

Changing `log4j.rootLogger=FINE, stdout` to `log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout` does hide all `DEBUG` from the console, so I know this file is being parsed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace

```
log4j.rootLogger=FINE, stdout
```

with

```
log4j.rootLogger=TRACE, stdout
```

And check here: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Level.html
and http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html

The second link says:

```
Loggers may be assigned levels. The set of possible levels, that is:

TRACE,
DEBUG,
INFO,
WARN,
ERROR and
FATAL
```

Answer (score 1):

The levels for log4j are differents from Java Loggin Framework.

For log4j, all the possible options are:

- `ALL`
- `TRACE`
- `DEBUG`
- `INFO`
- `WARN`
- `ERROR`
- `FATAL`
- `OFF`